# C# Shuffle Cards Windows Forms

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am working on an assignment for school ([Assignment Here)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4n_p06wAYacc1lzbG50ZU9wUTA/view?usp=sharing).

I am currently trying to shuffle a deck of cards. I have used PlayingCards from Codeplex (sorry, could only have two links...) to create a collection of cards to create a deck. Please help, when I click the Shuffle button, nothing happens. You can see my progress here it's easier to see the entire code: [Github](https://github.com/madelinelise/madeline_schimenti_a05_cards)

```
public void Shuffle()
{
    PlayingCards.Deck theDeck = new PlayingCards.Deck();

    random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < theDeck.Cards.Count; i++)
    {
        int second = random.Next(NUMBER_OF_CARDS);
        PlayingCards.Card temp = theDeck.Cards[i];
        theDeck.Cards[i] = theDeck.Cards[second];
        theDeck.Cards[second] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: theDeck.Cards.Count seems to have value as 0. So, the iteration is not happening..

Comment: You are right, when I debug I do see that it is equal to zero. However, I thought that to loop through the contents of a list you had to use .Count. This is my first attempt looping through the contents of a list, what do you suggest? When I try 52 it says "Out of Bounds".

Comment: @MadelineSchimenti - I had a look at the source for `Deck` on http://playingcards.codeplex.com/ and the class doesn't initialize the cards list with the actual cards - it is empty. That would be why the count is zero.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new instance of `PlayingCards.Deck`, shuffling it, and then throwing it away at the end of the shuffle.

```
PlayingCards.Deck theDeck = new PlayingCards.Deck();
```

You need to change the call to `Shuffle` to include `PlayingCards.Deck` as a parameter, so you should be doing this:

```
public void Shuffle(PlayingCards.Deck theDeck)
{
    random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < theDeck.Cards.Count; i++)
    {
        int second = random.Next(NUMBER_OF_CARDS);
        PlayingCards.Card
            temp = theDeck.Cards[i];
        theDeck.Cards[i] = theDeck.Cards[second];
        theDeck.Cards[second] = temp;
    }
}
```

You should also move the `new Random()` outside of this method as you may find that if you tried to create two shuffled decks immediately after one another that they'll have the same order because the seed `Random` uses is based on the system clock.

I had a look at the code you've got for adding the cards to the deck. You should use this code instead:

```
foreach (var face in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PlayingCards.CardSuits)).Cast<PlayingCards.CardSuits>())
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PlayingCards.CardValues)).Cast<PlayingCards.CardValues>())
    {
        theDeck.Cards.Add(new PlayingCards.Card(face, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Shuffle is not in PlayingCards.Deck. PlayingCards.Deck is actually part of a reference from http://playingcards.codeplex.com/. (We are required to use it in the assignment)

Comment: What class is `Shuffle` in?

Comment: If you want to shuffle an existing deck of cards you have to be able to reference it in `Shuffle` and not create a new deck.

Comment: Shuffle is currently in the Form1.cs, I have a button that calls the method when clicked. I do understand what you mean about referring to the existing deck, but maybe I'm not sure how to. The deck, to my knowledge is stored in PlayingCards.Deck.Cards (from the reference PlayingCards). PlayingCards.Deck.Cards is where the cards are dealt from (this works fine)

Comment: By replacing my CreateDeck method with your code, I was able to correctly shuffle! I believe my error was somewhere in how I was adding the cards to the deck. I knew there had to be a way to add each card to the deck in a loop, but since I am new to C# I wasn't sure about the syntax and I'm not very familiar with foreach yet. I got the assignment working to be submitted, and made comments saying I received help. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @MadelineSchimenti - No worries. If the answer helped don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. Good luck with the study.